# No genuine Hanafi fiqh book in Urdu!

Tags: hanafi, books

I am from a country where every scholar be it Hanafi (Deobandi and Barelvi) or Salafi is deep into sectarian and biddat (In case of Barelvi) stuff. Everyone other than their own sect is "Kafir", "Mushrik" and "Biddati". Being Hanafi myself, I am looking for a genuine Hanafi Fiqh book for a common Muslim in Urdu language, but after searching for days on the internet I got nothing. Some books are very short and contains only Fiqh of Ibadat and nothing about Muamalat, some contains both, but they are filled with poisonous sectarian stuff and some are too much detailed for a common Muslim. If someone here know about a genuine Hanafi fiqh book please tell me.
Thank You!

Comment: These kinds of questions are hardly on topic here. And Urdu is not the site language. You may find some English sources in [this meta post](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2934/13438)

Answer (score 1):

There are many classic hanafi fiqh works translated into Urdu. For example a quick search yields the Urdu translations of Mukhtasar Qudri ([vol 1](https://archive.org/stream/DarsENizamiDarjaSaniah2ndYear1/AnwaarUlQuduriUrduSharhAlQuduriVol1), [vol 2](https://archive.org/stream/DarsENizamiDarjaSaniah2ndYear1/AnwaarUlQuduriUrduSharhAlQuduriVol2) , [vol 3](https://archive.org/stream/DarsENizamiDarjaSaniah2ndYear1/AnwaarUlQuduriUrduSharhAlQuduriVol3)) and Hidayah ([16 volumes](https://archive.org/details/AHSANULHIDAYAHVOL03)) and  Durr al-Muhtar ([vol 1](https://archive.org/stream/fiqahanafi/Durr%20e%20Mukhtar/Durr%20e%20Mukhtar%20-%201) , [vol 2](https://archive.org/stream/fiqahanafi/Durr%20e%20Mukhtar/Durr%20e%20Mukhtar%20-%202#page/n0/mode/2up), [vol 3](https://archive.org/stream/fiqahanafi/Durr%20e%20Mukhtar/Durr%20e%20Mukhtar%20-%203#page/n0/mode/2up),[vol 4](https://archive.org/stream/fiqahanafi/Durr%20e%20Mukhtar/Durr%20e%20Mukhtar%20-%204#page/n0/mode/2up)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But these are extremely detailed commentaries of original works which are too much for a common muslim who is not a scholar. In Shia Jafari there many Urdu fiqh books written by different ayatollahs known as "Tauzeeh-Ul-Masail" and they are only 600 - 1000 pages books unfortunately this is not the case with Hanafi fiqh.